# Take data from List<class> and put it in to String object

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtable

I'm making an java simple app for better code learning that combine some gui on intellji.

I already have a main page and I'm just trying to make a popup Table That have all the data on my product this is my tableView CODE:

```
public class ProductTable extends JFrame
{
    private Model.product product;
    private List<product> list;

    public ProductTable() {
        list = product.ProductList();

        // headers for the table
        String[] columns = {"Product Name",
                "Quantity",
                "Expiration day",
                "Need fridge"};
        Object[][] data = new Object[][] {
        };

        // create table with data
        JTable table = new JTable(data, columns);

        // add the table to the frame
        this.add(new JScrollPane(table));
        this.setTitle("ProductList");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new ProductTable();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

In the `Product` class I have:

```
product.name = String
product.quantity = int
Product.Expiration_day = String
product.fridge = boolean
```

I want to load into the String Object

```
Data={ {product.name, product.quantity, Product.Expiration_day, Product.fridge} ,{.....,....,....,...}{..............}};
```

till i put in all off my data now i know how to know the size but i need load it one by one into the data object please can anyone guide through it?!

My Product code:

```
package Model;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class product
{
    private String product_name;
    private Integer product_quantity;
    private String experation_day;
    private boolean fridge = false;
    private boolean matched= false;
    private Connection connection;

    public product()
    {
        this.product_name = "";
        this.product_quantity = 0;
        this.experation_day = "";
    }

    public product(String product_name, Integer product_quantity, String experation_day) {
        this.product_name = product_name;
        this.product_quantity = product_quantity;
        this.experation_day = experation_day;
    }

    public Integer getProduct_quantity() {
        return product_quantity;
    }

    public String getExperation_day() {
        return experation_day;
    }

    public String getProduct_name()
    {
        return product_name;
    }

    public void setProduct_quantity(Integer product_quantity) {
        this.product_quantity = product_quantity;
    }

    public void setExperation_day(String experation_day) {
        this.experation_day = experation_day;
    }

    public void setProduct_name(String product_name)
    {
        this.product_name = product_name;
    }

    public List<product> ProductList() {

        String windownsUserName = System.getProperty("user.name");
        try
        {
            System.out.println("Connecting to a selected database...");
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Users\\"+windownsUserName+"\\IdeaProjects\\Software-engineer-final-project\\untitled\\src\\DButills\\account.db");
            System.out.println("Connected database successfully...");
            String sqlQuery = "SELECT product_name, product_amount, product_expration_date FROM products";
            PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            {

            }
            List<product> products = new ArrayList<>();
            while (rs.next()) {
                product product = new product();
                product.setProduct_quantity(rs.getInt("product_amount"));
                product.setProduct_name(rs.getString("product_name"));
                product.setExperation_day(rs.getString("product_expration_date"));
                products.add(product);
            }
            return products;

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Query failed: " + e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Loop through the product list,  appending data, commas, and braces to the result string as needed to build the desired format.

Comment: You can also write a toString method?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need ***String***? According to code you provided - what you need is an array ***Object[][]***, but filled with values, so simply loop over your product list and fill your ***data*** in correct order.

EDIT:

Look at this pseudocode, it should look somehow like this:

```
   String[] columns = {"Product Name",
            "Quantity",
            "Expiration day",
            "Need fridge"};
   Object[][] data = new Object[list.size()][columns.length];
   int columnCounter = 0;
   for(Product product : list) {
       data[columnCounter][0] = product.getName();
       data[columnCounter][1] = product.getQuantity();
       data[columnCounter][2] = product.getExpDay();
       data[columnCounter][3] = product.getNeedFridge();
       columnCounter++;
   }
```

Comment: i tried to do it but i cant find any boject[][].add(object[]) function.

Comment: there is any other idea or a solution for my situation?

Comment: You can't add into array object in java, syntax is data[i][j] = value;

Comment: its look grea but my code doesnt pop up the table like i planned to... so i cant see if its work

Answer (score 0):

```
'package viewer;
```

import Model.product;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;

import java.util.List;

public class ProductTable extends JFrame

{
    private Model.product product;

```
private Container c;

private JTable table;

Object[] mdata;

private List<product> list;

String[] columns = {"Product Name", "Quantity", "Expiration day"};  //headers for the table
int i=1;
```

private Object[][] data = new Object[][] { };

```
public ProductTable()
{
    list=product.ProductList();
   while(i<=list.size()) {

       mdata = new Object[]{list.get(i).getProduct_name(), list.get(i).getExperation_day(), list.get(i).getProduct_quantity().toString()};

       data[0][i]=mdata[0];

       data[1][i]=mdata[1];

       data[2][i]=mdata[2];

       i++;
   }

    //create table with data

    JTable table = new JTable(data, columns);

  //add the table to the frame

    this.setTitle("ProductList");

    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    setVisible(true);
}
```

}'